# How to detect whether a radio input is selected or not with multiple radio input?

Tags: jquery

I want to write some common jQuery code to validate a form. Here is my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>jquery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.registerBtn').on({
        click: function(evnt) {

          $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
              var CLASS = $(this).parent().parent().css({
                'background': 'red'
              });
              console.log(CLASS);
            }


          });
          evnt.preventDefault();
          var radioInput = $(".required:checked").val();
          console.log(radioInput);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="small">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" class="required"> Male
      </div>

      <div class="small">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" class="required"> Female
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="small">
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="Male" class="required"> text1
      </div>

      <div class="small">
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="Female" class="required"> text2
      </div>

    </div>



    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="registerBtn">
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

There are 2 sections of radio input. If I select an option for first section and hit submit button then background of second section should be red. But two section is being set as red. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use jquery **each** to check validation for each division. Here it is form-group.

Corrected **Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/4boh061y/

**HTML**

```
           <form action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="small">
                        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" class="required"> Male
                    </div>
                    <div class="small">
                        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" class="required"> Female
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="small">
                        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="Male" class="required"> text1
                    </div>
                    <div class="small">
                        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="Female" class="required"> text2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="registerBtn">
            </form>
```

**JQuery**

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('.registerBtn').on({
                    click: function(evnt){


                        $(".form-group").each(function(){
                            if($(this).find("input:radio:checked").length){
                                $(this).css({'background':'white'});
                                alert($(this).find("input:radio:checked").val());
                            }else{
                                $(this).css({'background':'red'});
                            }

                        }); 
                      evnt.preventDefault();
                    }
               });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this correct but i think you are checking on input type and for both section you have input type radio so i think you choose check using input name like this:

```
$('input[name=sex]').each(function(){
         if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
           var CLASS = $(this).parent().parent().css({'background':'red'});
           console.log(CLASS);
         }
 $('input[name=abc]').each(function(){
         if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
           var CLASS = $(this).parent().parent().css({'background':'red'});
           console.log(CLASS);
```

i dont know if this true i dont have experience with JS

Comment: And if you don't want the duplicate code you can do an external function for that.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.registerBtn').on({
        click: function(evnt) {

          $('.form-group input[type=radio]').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
              var CLASS = $(this).parent().css({
                'background': 'red'
              });
            }
            else
            {
            $(this).parent().css({
                'background': 'white'
              });
            }
          });
          evnt.preventDefault();
          var radioInput = $(".required:checked").val();
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>jquery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <div class="form-group" >
      <div class="small">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" class="required"> Male
      </div>

      <div class="small">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" class="required"> Female
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="small">
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="Male" class="required"> text1
      </div>

      <div class="small">
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="Female" class="required"> text2
      </div>

    </div>



    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="registerBtn">
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is approximate to my output. But Male & Female is a pair, If one is selected then it should be treated as selected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery there's no need to iterate on each member

```
 $('input[type=radio]').each
```

Just perform a query and jQuery will do the rest, like this:

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked')
```

Everything is red because both groups have the same name, they should have separete form names or use a selector to select the first form group only (not recommended):

```
$('div.form-group:first input[type=radio]:checked').parent().css({'background':'red'});
```

You can check the full solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aef796za/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

change `$(this).parent().parent().css()` to `$('input:radio:checked').parent().parent().css()` so it will work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.registerBtn').on({
    click: function(evnt) {

      $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
          var CLASS = $('input:radio:checked').parent().parent().css({
            'background': 'red'
          });
          console.log(CLASS);
        }
      });
      evnt.preventDefault();
      var radioInput = $('input:radio:checked').val();
      console.log(radioInput);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" class="required"> Male
    </div>

    <div class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" class="required"> Female
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="abc" value="text1" class="required"> text1
    </div>

    <div class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="abc" value="text2" class="required"> text2
    </div>

  </div>



  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="registerBtn">
</form>
```